What is the difference between the PHY sublayers PCS, PMA and PMD?
I'm reading Analog Device's Beginner's Guide to Ethernet. It's really good and goes into concepts like Manchester Encoding, 4B/5B, NRZT, MLT3 which seem to make sense to me. However, it kind of arbitrarily calls things part of the PCS layer, PMA layer, PMD layer, etc. and jumps around.
What is the intuitive role of each sublayer? And why do certain concepts (4B/5b, MLT3, etc.) fall into each layer?

4B/5B Encoding (PCS Layer) is primarily used for ensuring synchronization, error detection, and bit timing.
